# TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR to TYPE_3BYTE_BGR conversion

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I have a BufferedImage of TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR imageType with transparency and I want to convert it into TYPE_3BYTE_BGR BufferedImage. I tried to draw TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR image on TYPE_3BYTE_BGR one, but it changed colors.

The aim is to put transparent image on white background, because if one just writes TYPE_4BYTE_AGBR image into .jpg, he gets black ob transparent area.

Comment: What do you mean with "changed colors"? Some colors? Only pixels with alpha?

Comment: It looks like colors has been inverted. I think it just used ABG as BGR and ignored Red component of ABGR.

Comment: Can you please show the code you used to draw, that resulted in changed colors? I find it very strange + I'm curious. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that you need, you have to put the same color with 100% alpha in a new image with alpha channel.

```
// bufferedImage is your image.
if (bufferedImage.getType() == BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR) {
    BufferedImage bff = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    for (int y = 0; y < bufferedImage.getHeight(); ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bufferedImage.getWidth(); ++x) {
        int argb = bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y);
        bff.setRGB(x, y, argb & 0xFF000000); // same color alpha 100%
        }
    }
    return bff;
} else {
    return bufferedImage;
}
```

if you want to put a transparent image on a white background you should indeed use a new BufferedImage with different type. The code to do so is this:

```
// bufferedImage is your image.
if (bufferedImage.getType() == BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR) {
    for (int y = 0; y < bufferedImage.getHeight(); ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bufferedImage.getWidth(); ++x) {
            int argb = bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y);
            if((argb & 0x00FFFFFF) == 0x00FFFFFF){ //if the pixel is transparent
                bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, 0xFFFFFFFF); // white color.
            }
        }
    }
    return bufferedImage;
}
```